# Read CSV file in django

Tags: django, csv, python-2.7

Below is my code

**read_csv.py**

```
from www.models import Attendance , Employee

import csv
import datetime

dataReader = csv.reader(open('www/attendace.csv'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

dic = {}
for row in dataReader:
    if row[0] != 'Ac-No': # Ignore the header row, import everything else
        account_number = row[0]
        stime = row[2]
        if account_number not in dic:
            dic[account_number] = []

        dic[account_number].append(stime)

for acc, stimes in dic.iteritems():
    checkin = stimes.pop(0)
    print checkin
    employee = Employee.objects.get(acc_no= acc)
    print str(employee.acc_no)

    d = checkin[:-4].strip()
    check_in = datetime.datetime.strptime(d, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M" )

    check_out = None
    for stime in stimes:
        stime = stime[:-4].strip()
        stime = datetime.datetime.strptime(stime, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M" )

        if stime.date() == check_in.date():
            check_out = stime
            print check_out
        else:
            attend = Attendance()
            attend.check_in = check_in
            attend.check_out = check_out
            attend.employee = employee
            attend.save()
            check_in = stime
            check_out= None
```

I want to have for every `account_number`, `check_in` and `check_out` date, so I have dic with the employee `account_number` and the list of `stime`(`check_in` and `check_out` together).
The problem is I am getting the output only for 1 employee and its wrong, for example emp 1 has 3 records for checkin and checkout if I keep running employee 1 can have till 30 .. 
can someone help ?

Comment: Can you provide example of CSV and output?

Comment: 1,michael,5/28/2013 2:05 A5P5,Fingerpint,2,,,,,
1,michael,5/28/2013 2:06 A5P5,Fingerpint,2,,,,,

Comment: output is hard but its like " checkin checkout employee those r the headers and the records aare all employee 1